# How can I write this in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to come to terms with CoffeeScript after checking out LESS css yesterday, I was very impressed with that.

I'm more of a jQuery wiz than Raw Javascript so I find it a little confusing, but at the same time I think looking into CoffeeScript is good as it will help me to get a better understanding by analysing the output.

```
var Raw = (function($) {

    $(function() {
        Raw.initialize();
    });

    return {
        _current: '',
        initialize: function() {
            this.initGlobal();
            if(this.is('index')) {
                this.initIndex();
            }
            else if(this.is('single')) {
                this.initSingle();
            }
        },
        initGlobal: function() {
            atom_twitter();
            atom_loading();
            ratings();
        },
        initIndex: function() {
            atom_scroll();
        },
        initSingle: function() {
            atom_download();
        },
        is: function(page) {
            if(this._current == '') {
                this._current = $('body').attr('id');
            }
            return this._current == page;
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas where to start?

So far I have this:

```
Raw = (($) ->
  console.log 'hello world'
)(jQuery);
```

Which outputs:

```
(function() {
  var raw;

  raw = (function($) {
    return console.log('hello world');
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Well, I don't think the code will be _identical_, but the functionality can definitely be achieved, though.

Comment: I recommend migrating this question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @TrevorBurnham Is a moderator of some sort is able to do this?

Comment: @Brogrammer Yes, we can. But I am sure if this is on topic for Code Review.

Comment: This is *not* on topic for code review as this is asking how to *produce* new code going from one environment to another.  Code review requires *complete* code, and as such, this question does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
raw = do ($ = jQuery) ->
  $ raw.initialize
  {
    _current: ''
    initialize: ->
      @initGlobal()
      if @is 'index'
        @initIndex() 
      else if @is 'single'
        @initSingle()
    # and the rest...
  }
```

Note that there may be a problem with the code you're trying to port: A function passed to `$` will be run when the DOM is ready, or *immediately* if the DOM already is ready. So if the DOM is ready when this code runs, `raw.initialize` will be called before `raw` is defined, causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you've structured your code, it is pretty much a line by line conversion. I didn't bother with the $ conversion, but if you want you can just put `$ = jQuery` just after the `do` line.

```
Raw = null
do ($ = jQuery) ->

  Raw = 
    _current: ''
    initialize: ->
      @initGlobal()
      if @is 'index'
        @initIndex() 
      else if @is 'single'
        @initSingle()

    initGlobal: ->
      atom_twitter()
      atom_loading()
      ratings()
    initIndex: ->
      atom_scroll()
    initSingle: ->
      atom_download()

    is: (page) ->
      @_current = $('body').attr('id') if @_current == ''
      @_current == page

  $ -> Raw.initialize()
```

Comment: As of CoffeeScript 1.2.0, you can actually write `do ($ = jQuery) ->` to produce `(function($){...})(jQuery)`.

Comment: Good to know! That's very handy.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
Raw = (($) ->
  $ ->
    Raw.initialize()

  _current: ""
  initialize: ->
    @initGlobal()
    if @is("index")
      @initIndex()
    else @initSingle()  if @is("single")

  initGlobal: ->
    atom_twitter()
    atom_loading()
    ratings()

  initIndex: ->
    atom_scroll()

  initSingle: ->
    atom_download()

  is: (page) ->
    @_current = $("body").attr("id")  if @_current is ""
    @_current is page
)(jQuery)
```

if you want to convert your js into coffeescript, use the js2cofee converter on http://js2coffee.org/